# How to have Monit send an alert when a file does not exist, but not when it does exist?

Tags: monit

I have the following Monit check:

```
check file foo with path /run/foo
    if does not exist then alert
```

This sends an alert when /run/foo does not exist. But when I login to the server and create /run/foo, I don't want Monit to send *another* alert now that the file *does* exist. How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there no way to prevent Monit from alerting on a subset of an event. You can set *event filter* or *service filter* but you cannot filter at *failure* or *success* level.

Documentation : https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#Disabling-alerts-for-some-service